# Multiple code blocks in Razor and Parser Error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, using

I have an issue in my MVC site.

I have a using and a fieldlist in that, and in that a code block. If I close my using at the end, i have an error "Encountered end tag "fieldset" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?"

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <h1><strong>Create new Account</strong> / Basic data</h1>
                    </div
                </div>

                <form class="needs-validation AD-F-Needs-V" novalidate>

                    <div class="row p-3">
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
                            <div class="form-group AD-F-Mandatory">
                                @{
                                    var user = ViewBag.CurrentUser as UserProfile;
                                    var roleTypes = FindAllDerivedTypes<ProfileData>().Where(a => !a.Name.Contains("View"));
                                    var profileDatas = user.ProfileDatas.Select(a => GetObjectType(a.GetType()));
                                    roleTypes = roleTypes.Where(a => !profileDatas.Any(b => a.Name == b.Name)).ToList();
                                    var roles = (roleTypes as IEnumerable<Type>).ToDictionary(a => a.Name, b => GetResourceByName(ResourceManager, b.Name));


                                    <div class="AD-F-M-C AD-F-SSelect">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("typeSelector", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)roles.Select(a => new SelectListItem()))
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="AD-F-Acc">
                        <div class="AD-F-Acc-Content">
                            <div class="collapse show row p-3" id="sectionBasicData">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 mb-3">

                                    <div class="form-group AD-F-Mandatory">
                                        <label for="bdFirstName">First Name</label>
                                        <div class="AD-F-M-C">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(a => a.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "First Name", required = "required" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                                            <span class="AD-F-M-Asterix">
                                                <span class="mdi mdi-asterisk"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group AD-F-Mandatory">
                                        <label for="bdSecondName">Second Name</label>
                                        <div class="AD-F-M-C">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(a => a.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Last Name", required = "required" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                                            <span class="AD-F-M-Asterix">
                                                <span class="mdi mdi-asterisk"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>

    <div class="AD-card-body-footer AD-CBF-medium">

        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 d-flex justify-content-between">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</fieldset>

}
```

without the Using block it works well, but I need that for saving.

So it looks because there are more code blocks, it fails, but I need both somehow. I don't really know how I can use more different block at different places in a cshtml file, I tried to find solution on Google, but I did not find any really helpful article. 
How can I fix this ?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at [the help center article on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Right now it's very difficult to read your code due to the indentation and lack of formatting.

Comment: please mail(get email from my profile) your code. I'll help you asap,your current code is in improper manner

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have an unnecessary '}' at `@Html.DropDownList("typeSelector", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)roles.Select(a => new SelectListItem()}))`

Remove that and it should be fine.

Comment: I just cutted that line for pasate here, because that was very long.
As I wrote if I remove the using and the opening and closing {} of using, works fine